# Is there something like Jenkins pipeline scripts for Bamboo?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bamboo

In Jenkins I setup my tasks using groovy pipline scripts stored in [git](/questions/tagged/git) or [subversion](/questions/tagged/subversion).

This way I only need to setup the input of the required parameters.
The processing (additional checkouts, installation, builds, tests and other ansible tasks) are defined in the pipline script.

My question is: Is there a way to do somtehing similar with bamboo?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Bamboo has that natively but there are plugins such as this one:  (https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.cobalt.cdpipeline.cdpipeline/server/overview).

Atlassian also has a different product called Bitbucket pipeline (https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) that may be more similar to what you want but it's more of a CircleCI type of Pipeline.

Comment: Thanks AnthonyC. Your marketplace link looks interesting, but does this plugin store the piplines in SCM (git, svn)?
With the second one I guess I'll loose the power of jenkins and my process has also to work with SVN.

Comment: No idea about the plugin since I don't use bamboo anymore (migrated from bamboo -> pipeline).

Answer (score 0):

You can have Bitbucket pipeline if you are using Bitbucket Cloud
https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines

Or Bamboo Specs https://confluence.atlassian.com/bameap/bamboo-specs-883185038.html if you are hosting your own Bamboo Server.

I'm looking into Bamboo specs right now and looks good and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

As of Bamboo 6.3+ there is now support for [YAML specs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-yaml-938844479.html) and configuration as code.  If you are using Bitbucket cloud then this functionality is built into [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines).